# linux Vagrant ubuntu/xenial different login user in different machine

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I having a script to run Vagrant base box (ubuntu/xenial64).
The login name vary in different machine, some machines login with `ubuntu`, some are logging as `vagrant`, this make my consecutive script not functioning

Anyone knowing this issue?
Thanks

Edited: Added Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    sudo su
    cd
    pwd
    echo -e "root\nroot" | passwd root
    sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin no/PermitRootLogin yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    cp -rvf /home/vagrant/.ssh/ /root/
    true
  SHELL
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--macaddress1', '${mac//:}']
  end
end
```

Comment: I have the same issue, starting today. building a new machine from the latest ubuntu/xenial64 box uses vagrant as default ssh user but when I did the same task last week using the same vagrantfile I got the ubuntu user as the default one. Strange indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Vagrant image has only one "non-root" user. 
So, you can modify your Vagrant file to copy files from any user we can find in `/home` folder:

```
cp -rvf /home/*/.ssh/ /root/
```

Also, I see that you do `sudo su` in provision script. It is not necessary, because by default [vagrant's shell provisioning](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html) runs with `privileged = true`:

The final `Vagrantfile` is:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    cd
    pwd
    echo -e "root\nroot" | passwd root
    sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin no/PermitRootLogin yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    cp -rvf /home/*/.ssh/ /root/
    true
  SHELL
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--macaddress1', '${mac//:}']
  end
end
```

Comment: I understood there is only a non-root user, but why even i run same base box image, it login as differrnt user (either ubuntu or vagrant) in different machines?